# How to create a complex object in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I need to create a complex object, which it's value needed to be computed or copy from another object.

the object I need to create

```
interface A extends B {
key1: string
key2: {
is's a complex object with many keys
}
}
```

I use these code

```
const a: A = Object.assign({}, b); //ts error here
a.key1 = around 10 lines of calc
a.key2 = around 10 lines of calc
```

but got an error `TS2741: Property 'key1, key2' is missing in type 'a' but required in type 'A'.`

Is there a way to create an object **in multiple lines** without coding unreadable code like `Object.assign({}, b, {key1: 10line, key2: 10line})`?

Comment: When asking questions, please don't abbreviate every bit of code and the error. Post a full example, the full exact error and am exact description of what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

This is a way how i asign my complex Variables. I used no interface for vetter understanding.

```
   let myObject: { key: { subkey: string } } = {key: {subkey: ""}};

    myObject = {
      ...myObject,
      key: { subkey: "value" }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use the latest standard, you can use object destructing which is basically a sugar for Object.assign(). The syntax uses triple dots "..."

```
const a: A = {...b, key1: /*Complex calc*/, key2: /*Complex calc*/};
```